# date formating in R

Tags: r

Final Output

```
|   Date    |  New_Date |
|-----------| --------- |    
|1967-07-01 |           |
|1967-07-02 |           |
|1967-07-03 |           |
|1967-07-04 |           |
|1967-07-05 |           |
|1967-07-06 |           |
|1967-07-07 |  07-July  |
|1967-07-08 |           |
|1967-07-09 |           |
|1967-07-10 |           |
|1967-07-11 |           |
|1967-07-12 |           |
|1967-07-13 |           |
|1967-07-14 |  14-July  |
```

Is there any function or library I can use to get "New_Date" (Final output every 7 day)?
I've tried this code but I am not getting the desired *Final output

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(New_Date <- seq.Data(Date, by = 7),
         format(New_Date, format = "%d-%b))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(New_date = case_when((row_number() -1) %% 7 + 1 == 7 ~ 
            format(Date, '%d-%b'), TRUE ~ ''))
```

-output

```
      Date New_date
1  1967-07-01         
2  1967-07-02         
3  1967-07-03         
4  1967-07-04         
5  1967-07-05         
6  1967-07-06         
7  1967-07-07   07-Jul
8  1967-07-08         
9  1967-07-09         
10 1967-07-10         
11 1967-07-11         
12 1967-07-12         
13 1967-07-13         
14 1967-07-14   14-Jul
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('1967-07-01'), length.out = 14, by = '1 day'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a index of every 7 days,change the format of those dates and create a new column.

```
inds <- seq(7, nrow(df), 7)
df$New_Date <- ''
df$New_Date[inds] <- format(df$Date[inds], '%d-%b')
df

#         Date New_Date
#1  1967-07-01         
#2  1967-07-02         
#3  1967-07-03         
#4  1967-07-04         
#5  1967-07-05         
#6  1967-07-06         
#7  1967-07-07   07-Jul
#8  1967-07-08         
#9  1967-07-09         
#10 1967-07-10         
#11 1967-07-11         
#12 1967-07-12         
#13 1967-07-13         
#14 1967-07-14   14-Jul
```

If `Date` column is not of Date type run `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)` first.